# Structural typing using embedded type - GO

Tags: go, structural-typing

In the below code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type People interface {
    sayHello()
    getDetails()
}

type Person struct {
    name        string
    age         int
    city, phone string
}

// A person method
func (p Person) sayhello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hi, I am %s, form %s\n", p.name, p.city)
}

// A person method
func (p Person) getDetails() {
    fmt.Printf("[Name: %s, Age: %d, City: %s, Phone: %s]\n", p.name, p.age, p.city, p.phone)
}
```

---

`Person` is [structurally typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) with `People`, because it implemented behavior of `People`

For the below code:

```
type Speaker struct {
    Person     // type embedding for composition
    speaksOn   []string
    pastEvents []string
}

func main() {
    obj1 := Speaker{Person{"aa", 23, "ww", "234"}, []string{"aa", "bb"}, []string{"dd", "ee"}}
    obj2 := Speaker{Person{"aa", 23, "ww", "234"}, []string{"aa", "bb"}, []string{"dd", "ee"}}
    obj3 := Speaker{Person{"aa", 23, "ww", "234"}, []string{"aa", "bb"}, []string{"dd", "ee"}}
    peopleList := [...]People{obj1, obj2, obj3}
    obj1.getDetails() 
    obj1.sayhello()
}
```

Why `obj1.getDetails()` is getting resolved? Is it because, `Speaker` type has embedded `Person` type and `Person` type is structurally typed with `People` interface type?

Comment: Can you add the definition of `getDetails()` method, please?

Comment: @overexchange yup sorry about that, misread it the first time. Methods and fields of an embedded type get *promoted* and which allows the embedding type can access them "directly".

Comment: This is just [how embedding works](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) and has nothing to do with the interface (deleting the interface definition doesn't change anything, because the interface isn't *used* anywhere).

Comment: ... again if you do a quick ctrl/cmd+f for the word "promoted" on the golang spec's page you'll find more info about it.

Comment: @Peter Why not? `peopleList := [...]People{obj1, obj2, obj3}`

Comment: @overexchange Peter wrote the comment before you added the use of the interface. Still it has no effect on whether or not you can call `getDetails` on `obj1`. `obj1` is of type `Speaker` which embeds `Person` which implements `getDetails`, that's why `obj1.getDetails()` works. For `obj1.getDetails()` the interface `People` is not necessary. For `[...]People{ ... }` to work, the interface is necessary, obviously since you're referencing it by name in the composite literal.

Comment: @mkopriva `[...]People{obj1,obj2,obj3}` is allowed because each literal(object) is implementing `People` interface.

Comment: @overexchange I didn't say anything to the contrary. However your question is: *"Why obj1.getDetails() is getting resolved?"* so please lets stay focused. The answer to that question is, as already pointed out by Peter, embedding.

Comment: @mkopriva  Does this line `obj1.getDetails()` have nothing to do with Structural typing?

Comment: @overexchange Take a look at this code: https://play.golang.org/p/rg0V_2KtR4z as you can see it works without the `People` interface. So the answer to *"Why `obj1.getDetails()` is getting resolved?"* cannot possibly contain a reference to interfaces, right? And I don't know anything about structural typing so I can't answer your other question with confidence, but my guess is that, no, it has nothing to do with structural typing.

Comment: ... maybe *nothing* is too strong a word, but I certainly think that the emphasis that you're placing on structural typing is too high. It is not something that is ever mentioned in the spec, at least not directly, and to understand the language you are better off with the concepts that the spec relies on.

Comment: "Structural typing" isn't something you *do*, it isn't something you *write*, it's a fundamental quality of the language, and an extremely broad software engineering concept.